# Unable to open browser on Foreground using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run a script in python of Selenium Webdriver using Pycharm. in order to open my browser, Browser does open, but on background and after sometime gets quit.

```
Class Automation:
    def Chrome():
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
        driver.get('https://www.google.com')

auto = Automation
auto.Chrome()
```

Please Tell me if I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Web Browser` opens up but on remains in the background, use the following code block to bring it in the focus :

```
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
driver.execute_script("window.focus();")
```